# Difference between diagram EA et class diagram

Tags: database, uml, class-diagram

What is the difference between EA diagram and et class diagram?
EA diagram shows how our data is stored in the database and the relationships between them. While the class diagram shows the objects that are manipulated in the system, the business classes.

In the image below, I have presented these two diagrams. Your comments are welcome.

[image: EA diagram vs class diagram]

If the class diagram highlights the objects that must be in the system, how we can specify (Employe, DG, TeamLeader) the Person class at the time of implementation known in the database we have the table Person which is linked to Role and that with the time the data of this table can be modified (add, edit).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your post includes two questions: (1) What is the difference... and (2) How can we specify...  In your post, you already give the answer to (1), so I assume your focus is on question (2). However, I don't understand this question. The last sentence in your post is very long and the English grammar is not correct. Please split it up in multiple sentences.

Comment: It is normal to have a class diagram focusing on the business domain and another class diagram specifying the physical database structure. Do you want to create a third diagram specifying how the two are mapped? I don't know of any standard way of mapping a generalization relationship to a class representing a database table.